# Android permission granted but still permission denied

Tags: android, permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have 3 different activitys on my project. First activity contains all permissions request. App has all permissions granted and still cannot write file on sdcard. If I close app and starting that again then I can write file on sdcard. Is there anyway update permissions for multiple activity.

```
public class PermissionActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public static final int REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS = 1;
private static int TIME_OUT = 2000;
private String TAG = "tag";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_permission);

    Locale locale = new Locale("en");
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    this.getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null);

    if(checkAndRequestPermissions()) {
        // carry on the normal flow, as the case of  permissions  granted.
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // This method will be executed once the timer is over
                // Start your app main activity

                Intent i = new Intent(PermissionActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

                // close this activity
                finish();
            }
        }, TIME_OUT);
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Permission callback called-------");
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS: {

            Map<String, Integer> perms = new HashMap<>();
            // Initialize the map with both permissions
            perms.put(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
            perms.put(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
            perms.put(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
            perms.put(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
            // Fill with actual results from user
            if (grantResults.length > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++)
                    perms.put(permissions[i], grantResults[i]);
                // Check for both permissions
                if (perms.get(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                        && perms.get(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                        && perms.get(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                        && perms.get(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "all permission granted");

                    // process the normal flow
                    Intent i = new Intent(PermissionActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                    //else any one or both the permissions are not granted
                } else {
                    Log.d(G.mLogTag, "Some permissions are not granted ask again ");
                    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                            || ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR)
                            || ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                            || ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)) {
                        showDialogOK("Service Permissions are required for this app",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        switch (which) {
                                            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                                                checkAndRequestPermissions();
                                                break;
                                            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                                                // proceed with logic by disabling the related features or quit the app.
                                                finish();
                                                break;
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                    }
                    else {
                        explain("You need to give some mandatory permissions to continue. Do you want to go to app settings?");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private boolean checkAndRequestPermissions(){
    int writeStoragePermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(PermissionActivity.this,
            android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    int writeCalenderPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR);
    int fineLocationPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    int coarseLocationPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);

    List<String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();
    if (writeStoragePermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        listPermissionsNeeded.add(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    if (writeCalenderPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        listPermissionsNeeded.add(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR);
    if (fineLocationPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        listPermissionsNeeded.add(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    if (coarseLocationPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        listPermissionsNeeded.add(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
    if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, listPermissionsNeeded
                        .toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]),
                REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

private void showDialogOK(String message, DialogInterface.OnClickListener okListener) {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setMessage(message)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", okListener)
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", okListener)
            .create()
            .show();
}
private void explain(String msg){
    final android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    dialog.setMessage(msg)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
                    //  permissionsclass.requestPermission(type,code);
                    startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS,
                            Uri.parse("package:fi.maxitors.mydiscgolfapp")));
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
                    finish();
                }
            });
    dialog.show();
}
```

}

Above is my permission asking activity. I'm sorry for the bad English.

Comment: The permission is granted to the entire app as soon as the user approves it. If you still can't write to external storage, it's either something else, or the permission wasn't actually approved.

Comment: I think my permission asking is working fine, but its not granted immediately those permissions. If I go app settings and there it will show that app has permissions and still cannot create file or folder. If app restarted then no problem.

Comment: Android app permissions are handled with UID permissions. Permission is granted to the UID that your app runs as. Restarting your app doesn't change anything about this UID or what its permissioning is.

Comment: Joonas, did you resolve this. I have exactly the same issue. My app New Playlist Manager is unable to create a new folder on the external sdcard despite having ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) returning true.

Comment: No. I think this is issue/bug in Android. My temperary fix: Say to user to start application again and then I force stop app from code. Issues is only Android 6.0 and newer.

Comment: Did you get a solution for this ??
I'm having exact same problem but in Android PIE.gave all permissions but it does not work for 1st time and after restart everything is fine.

Comment: I updated everything and then problems was gone. I think problem was in gradle, but I am not sure.

Comment: This did not work on Android 11. (Does work on Android 7.) Worked around the problem by prompting user to go to the settings app and give the permissions there. To do this programmatically in A11 I think you have to use an 'Intent'.

Answer (score 5):

Apps targeting Android 10 (API level 29) and higher are given scoped access into an external storage device, or scoped storage, by default. Such apps can see only their app-specific directory

1. Temp Fix-

   <manifest ... >
   <application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" ... >
   ...
2. permanent Fix-
   openFileDescriptor

Answer (score 2):

You need to also add READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission to read data from the device.

I think this has to do with the fact that Android gives automatically read permission when write ones are granted, but probably for his own bug doesn't do it in certain circumstances. In fact from documentation,

> Note: If your app uses the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission, then it
>   implicitly has permission to read the external storage as well.

at page https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files.html

I had a situation where for testing after having installed the apk on the device, i granted permission with the command

`adb shell pm grant com.blippar.ar.android.debug  android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`

that triggered the behaviour you observed. Instead giving both the previous and the

`adb shell pm grant com.blippar.ar.android.debug  android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`

solved the issue.

Comment: Granting permission using ABD solved my problem on a Heawei device which was throwing permission denied despite granting runtime permisssion (API 26)

Answer (score 0):

I have been having the same issue and I noticed this as soon as I upgraded to Gradle version 3.1.0. Try reverting to 3.0.1 if you upgraded.

Answer (score 0):

May be issue in the selected build variant.
Scenario is:

1. you build app in RELEASE, then run, approve the permission, write a file
2. rebuild app in DEBUG, then run (with deinstall earlier RELEASE variant, so UID may change), then try to access the file populated in (1)
3. UID changed, file(path) not owned, denial access occurs.